# Custom Extension not showing up within experimental instance

Tags: c#, vsix

I have a VSIX extension that I created which shows up in Visual Studio 2010 and works as designed.

However I am attempting to build some Visual Studio automation which relies on this Extension and although its present in the project where I am building my automation package, when I run the package project, the visual studio experimental solution loads no problem, however when I look within the Extension Manager I do not see my registered Extension (even though it shows up within my Visual Studio project where I am building my extension.

The extension is a custom shell for LightSwitch which may be a clue as to why it is not showing within my experimental instance of Visual Studio, not sure as I see other extensions I built and registered for LightSwitch showing up.

Of course my issue is that when I attempt to load a solution that has a dependency on my LightSwitch extension, which otherwise loads fine outside of the Experimental Instance, fails due to the fact it can't locate my custom extension when I try to load the solution within my experimental solution.

Answer (score 4):

Try to reset Exp hive. Click on Start>All Programs>Visual Studio SDK>Reset the Experimental hive.

Also you should check that you run/debug your extension via custom debug command in IDE 'devenv /RootSuffix exp'.

What I always did when similar problems appear - I checked what I have in windows registry for experimental hive (whther all the parts of my extension are registered OK there)